# Regexp to match file name without the path

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this code to find blank spaces in a file name in a SharePoint list attachment.

```
function PreSaveAction() {
    var attachment;
    var filename = "";
    var fileNameSpecialCharacters = new RegExp('\\s', 'g');
    try {
        attachment = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].firstChild;
        filename = attachment.data;
    } catch (e) {}
    if (fileNameSpecialCharacters.test(filename)) {
        alert("Please remove the special characters and white spaces from file attachment name.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In IE it checks white space in the 'whole path' instead of the file name. In all other browsers it works fine,

Can anyone help me to make this code check the file name only, not the whole path?

Comment: What does the string in `filename` look like? Does it vary from browser to browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split off the file name from the path name. Then test the file name only.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this? I am new to Javascript and coding.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from what stema said, this will check both `/` and `\`

```
\s(?=[^/\\]*$)
```

Comment: -1 the OP wants to find whitespace in the filename, your expression matches anything from the first slash till the last whitespace.

Comment: I realized that, should have checked Regexr before posting from my memory. Adding (/|\\\) to your solution should work on any OS.

Comment: You can't do an alternation in a character class (and its not necessary) `\s(?=[^/\\]*$)` is fine. I am not sure what is allowed in a file name. If `\ ` is the divider, is then `/` allowed as part of the filename or not? If not, then your solution is fine.

Comment: Seems like you are right again. I've seen all sorts of pathnames in windows that's why I thought about `/` and `\ `

Comment: is this fine? -- var fileNameSpecialCharacters = new RegExp('\s(?=[^\\]*$)', 'g');

Comment: Try new RegExp('\\s(?=[^/\\\\\]*$)', 'g');

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
\s(?=[^\\]*$)
```

That means find whitespace but only if there is no `\` ahead till the end of string.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vflq)

But of course this will work only if the character that divides the directories is the `\`. Maybe JavaScript can get this character from the OS somehow (I don't know JavaScript in that depth)?

Comment: I have changed my regexp as per your suggestion - var fileNameSpecialCharacters = new RegExp(\s(?=[^\\]*$)); but it's not working

Comment: @Sijo what do you mean by "its not working"? creating an error message or match the wrong things? If wrong matching, what does it wrong match?